# MySQL double to PostgreSQL double precision works, but default column value does not exist in schema.rb dump

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I converted a MySQL database to PostgreSQL in a Rails app, and the MySQL `double` column was converted to a `double precision` column in PostgreSQL.

The problem is that even if the PostgreSQL structure has this column with a default value of "0::double precision", `rake db:schema:dump` does not add this default value.

Therefore, when a model instance is created, the default value is not auto-assigned, and instead its value is `nil`.

Now, I'm on Rails 4.1.6, and this happens because the column type is not listed [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L82-L142) (AFAIK).  What is strange (to me) is why this hasn't been added yet.

What could be the recommended approach here?  Change the column type in PostgreSQL?

A `\d payments` from inside `psql` says:

```
                                       Table "public.payments"
     Column     |            Type             |                       Modifiers                       
----------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('payments_id_seq'::regclass)
 credit_card_id | integer                     | not null default 0
 order_id       | integer                     | not null default 0
 amount         | double precision            | not null default 0::double precision
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at     | timestamp without time zone | not null
 authorization  | character varying(510)      | default NULL::character varying
Indexes:
    "payments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "credit_card_id" btree (credit_card_id)
    "purchase_order_id_1" btree (order_id)
```

and the corresponding section of `schema.rb` says:

```
create_table "payments", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "credit_card_id",             default: 0, null: false
  t.integer  "order_id",                   default: 0, null: false
  t.float    "amount",                                 null: false
  t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
  t.string   "authorization",  limit: 510
end
```

Comment: What does PostgreSQL think the table looks like? Connect your database with `psql` from the command line and `\d table_name`. What does the table look like in `schema.rb`?

Comment: psql: https://gist.github.com/favrik/b34637a19d91b56285c9  schema.rb: https://gist.github.com/favrik/a90bfe77720fab71574e   The column I'm referring to is `amount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right about the problem being in `extract_value_from_default` inside ActiveRecord; AR tends to ignore anything from the database that it doesn't understand and it doesn't understand the `::double precision` cast in `amount`'s definition so AR assumes that there is no default.

Whatever tool you used to convert your MySQL schema and database to PostgreSQL is also sort of at fault. The type cast is not needed, PostgreSQL can convert an integer to double precision all by itself so just:

```
amount double precision default 0
```

is sufficient. If you want some sort of reminder in the default that you're dealing with floating point then you could use:

```
amount double precision default 0.0
```

AR should understand either of those.

The easiest solution is to fix the default value inside the database and removing the type cast. Going behind AR's back and doing a manual ALTER TABLE should be sufficient. From `psql`, you could say:

```
alter table payments alter column amount set default 0;
```

or inside a migration:

```
def up
  connection.execute('alter table payments alter column amount set default 0')
end
```

After that, your `db:schema:dump` should include the new default value and newly created `Payment`s should have an amount of zero.

---

As an aside, you might want to switch to the `numeric` type (AR calls this `t.decimal`) inside the database. Using floating point for money rarely ends well.

Comment: Thanks, you rock! :D    In fact, I'm using this [converter](https://github.com/favrik/mysql-postgresql-converter), so I will just modify that to add an AR recognizable default.  You're absolutely right about the column type not good for money of course.  It's a rails 1 to rails 4 migration...